# How to get add term form of taxonomy inside node type form?

Tags: 8, forms, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to render taxonomy add term form inside content type ('article') add form. (`node/add/article`)

In `hook_form_alter`, I called this callback function on abutton.

```
public function _cvv_ajax_callback(VocabularyInterface $taxonomy_vocabulary) {
    $taxonomy_vocabulary = 'cvv';
    $term = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->create(['vid' => $taxonomy_vocabulary->id()]);
    return \Drupal::entityFormBuilder()->getForm($term);
  }
```

But this is not return form in my node/add page, rather giving me error:

> error   php   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Missing
>   bundle for entity type taxonomy_term in
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doCreate()

I tried

```
if ($vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('jenis_dokumen')) {
  module_load_include('inc', 'taxonomy', 'taxonomy.admin');
  $edit = array();
  $taxonomy_form = drupal_get_form('taxonomy_form_term', $edit ,$vocabulary);
  return drupal_render($taxonomy_form);
}
```

but this is also not working in Drupal 8.

Also tried:

```
 $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\taxonomy\Controller\TaxonomyController::addForm','plan_features');
```

didn't worked :'(

Lastly I tried [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) , the problem with module is, when a add term form get rendered inside node type form and if you do

`kint($form_id);` inside `hook_form_alter`, you won't get any form id for this inline form. Hence if you want to add custom validations for the term title, it won't be achievable even by hooks this module provides.

Please  suggest a way to do this.

Comment: What was the error message of the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this module? It's pretty much what you could need:

[Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form)

Comment: This is a good solution, Inline Entity Form is on by default on D8 Lightning distribution.

Comment: But altering inline entity form is also a big trouble. Because this module provides 3 hooks. So I want to add custom validation on term name, it is not achievable through these hooks.

Comment: Also, there's no way even to get the form id of the form rendered by "Inline Entity form."

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution should work. Use the name of the vocabulary instead of the id ..

```
$term = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->create(['vid' => $taxonomy_vocabulary->label()]);
```